# using two buttons out of twelve at once

Tags: android, button

I have 12 buttons in my activity..i want to use them in the following way:

Two buttons should be allowed to click at once and when those two are clicked then some action to be performed..if this action is successful, these two buttons must be "invisible" and if this action is unsuccessful, again there must be option to click any of the two buttons out of all twelve..

i have set the layout of this activity and all the twelve buttons as well.I have also set the onClick method for all of the buttons.

[ADDITION]

i mean only two out of twelve buttons be allowed to press at once..any two of them..and after that the output of both the buttons be compared..if they are equal then the buttons be invisible else they are still there and once again the user gets a chance to click two buttons..

[CODE]

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(0,90);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
button1.startAnimation(rotate);

Random r = new Random();
int next = r.nextInt(5) + 1;
imgV1.setImageResource(images[next]);  //imageView1 is given a random image

AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0,1);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
imgV1.startAnimation(alpha);
arg0.clearAnimation();
}});

imgV1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1,0);
alpha.setFillAfter(true);
imgV1.startAnimation(alpha);

RotateAnimation rotate = new RotateAnimation(90,0);
rotate.setFillAfter(true);
button1.startAnimation(rotate);
arg0.clearAnimation();
}});
```

button click gives a random image..image click gives the button back..now i want that when two buttons are clicked and if they have the same image, then they both go invisible..else they both turn back to the buttons and user can again click on any of the two buttons..

Each button has an imageView behind it in the layout..

Comment: Let me clarify. Let buttons are b1,b2,b3..b12. Now, what do you want? Press some b2&b5 at once with two fingers OR press b1 and then you have to press one more button to complete action?

Comment: first one button be pressed then other be pressed..the second option u gave

Comment: You can have a flag, set it to true when first button is pressed, when next time button is pressed, if flag is set....compare/process your logic. After your process, set flag to false and set button visibility as per the result. Simple !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K.. Now I got it. So, there will be 6 images in your Drawable. Here we go..

Make an Integer array of size 12 to store id's of 6 images. say, `int[] images={R.drawable.img1,...};`
Also `Button firstClick;Drawable back;` to know the first clicked button.
Now, our onClick will be as,

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(count<2){// means first click
firstClick=(Button)v;
back=v.getBackground();
                action=images[0];// button1 pressed so index 0
v.setBackgroundResource(action);
v.setEnabled(false);
                count++;
            }
            else{//second click
                count=0;
                if(action==images[0]){
v.setBackgroundResource(action);
v.setEnabled(false);

}else{
v.setBackgroundDrawable(back); //roll back to old background

firstClick.setBackgroundDrawable(back);

}

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: images are not being used as the background..instead i have created imageView behind every button where the images are being shown..lemme add the code of one button that will make it easier for you to understand..

Comment: Thats nice. Then make corresponding changes to make button and imageview 'visibility' and 'enabled'.

Comment: But how can I compare images of two image views?

Comment: Inside your button click, `action=images[next];` and inside image click, `if(action==imgv1.getid())`

Comment: now in this case can you please modify my code or tell me what modifications i should make..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setVisibility()` method of view(Button) to set it's visibility on or off.

```
Button b = ( Button )findViewById( R.id.button1 );
b.setVisibility( b.INVISIBLE );
b.setVisibility( b.VISIBLE );
```

Comment: this will only set the visibility but i want that after two buttons be pressed only then this kind of action takes place..i mean only two out of twelve buttons be allowed to press at once..any two of them..and after that the output of both the buttons be compared..if they are equal then the buttons be invisible else they are still there and once again the user gets a chance to click two buttons..

Comment: at the start, set any of the 10 buttons' visibility off, and rest of the two's visibility on.
In the onClickListener of the 2 visible buttons, you can compare whatever you want to, and then change the visibility of other buttons

Answer (score 0):

The logic that I thought is like,

You should have two variables in hand globally.

1 for counting button clicks and 2nd for storing first click action(Based upon your app).

I'm taking `int action=0,count=0;` as global variables.

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(count<2){// means first click
                action=1;// button1 pressed
                count++;
            }
            else{//second click
                count=0;
                //Here perform your action and based upon it, set visibility. Previous click is available in 'action'

            }
        }
    });
```

Repeat this for all button clicks. Thats it. I'll prefer your own method to be called for perform actions and set visibility.

Comment: brother your logic is very helpful..it solved my this problem but created another one for me..actually i am designing blocks game that we used to play in Windows 98.. in this there are total twelve buttons..when we click a button, it gives an image..now when the other button is clicked too, it too would give an image and if both of these images are same, the button and the imageView both vanishes..else the images rotate back to the buttons and the user can again click any button..